# Wordpress Theme changes the permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, short-url

Hello im using a free Wordpress-Theme (Ari) from elmastudio,

I have the same Problem like this Description:
http://support.mailpoet.com/knowledgebase/confirmation-and-unsubscribe-pages-are-blank/

I try to unsubscribe the Newsletter and the URL in the Newsletter:

```
mydomain.com/?email_id=3&user_id=5&urlpassed=W3N1YnNjcmlwdGlvbnNfbGlua10%3D&controller=stats&hash=d37a050b840066e7f26cc5df65d6f3cc&action=analyse&wysija-page=1&wysijap=subscriptions
```

will be reduce to:

```
mydomain.com/?wysijap=subscriptions
```

I deleted all SEO Plugins and cant finde further perma Link Settings, which will reduce the url.

Can you give me a tip to find those function in the theme?
PS: The Newsletter / perma links works fine with the Default-Theme

best regards
Ahmet

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is reuploading or upgrading your wordpress code

Comment: Wordpress and all Plugins/Themes are up to date.